# Scala Type mismatch when a generic type operates on the same generic type

Tags: scala, generics, types, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have an generic case class Route that takes in a List of subclasses of Location. However in the following method I get a type mismatch in the call to `distance` `expected: head.T, actual: T`

```
case class Route[T <: Location](route: List[T]) {
  def measureDistance: Double = {
    def measure(head: T, tail: List[T], acc: Double = 0.0): Double = tail match {
      case Nil => acc
      case h :: t => measure(h, t, head.distance(h) + acc)
    }
    if (route.isEmpty) 0.0
    else measure(route.head, route.tail)
  }
}
```

The basic abstract Location class is as follows

```
abstract class Location(val name: String) {

type T <: Location

def distance(that: T): Double
}
```

As head and h both come from the same list `route` I can't understand why these are not the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if F-bounded polymorphism is what you want in this case:

```
abstract class Location[L <: Location[L]](val name: String) {
  def distance(that: L): Double
}

case class Route[T <: Location[T]](route: List[T]) {
  def measureDistance: Double = {
    def measure(head: T, tail: List[T], acc: Double = 0.0): Double = tail match {
      case Nil => acc
      case h :: t => measure(h, t, head.distance(h) + acc)
    }
    if (route.isEmpty) 0.0
    else measure(route.head, route.tail)
  }
}
```

However, you might also consider using a `Metric`-typeclass instead:

```
trait Metric[L] {
  def dist(a: L, b: L): Double
}

case class Route[T: Metric](route: List[T]) {
  def measureDistance: Double = {
    def measure(head: T, tail: List[T], acc: Double = 0.0): Double = tail match {
      case Nil => acc
      case h :: t => measure(h, t, implicitly[Metric[T]].dist(head, h) + acc)
    }
    if (route.isEmpty) 0.0
    else measure(route.head, route.tail)
  }
}
```

The latter solution would be applicable to more types, for example to `(Double, Double)`, even if they don't inherit from `Location`.

Here is the typeclass solution again, but with slightly more polished Cats-style syntax that avoids `implicitly`:

```
trait Metric[L] {
  def dist(a: L, b: L): Double
}

object Metric {
  def apply[T](implicit m: Metric[T]): Metric[T] = m
}

case class Route[T: Metric](route: List[T]) {
  def measureDistance: Double = {
    def measure(head: T, tail: List[T], acc: Double = 0.0): Double = tail match {
      case Nil => acc
      case h :: t => measure(h, t, Metric[T].dist(head, h) + acc)
    }
    if (route.isEmpty) 0.0
    else measure(route.head, route.tail)
  }
}
```

Comment: The first solution solves the type mismatch. However, I'm now unsure how subclasses of `Location` should be implemented. I can write them similar to below:
    `case class SubLocation(override val name: String) extends Location(name) {
      type T = SubLocation
      override def distance(that: Location[T]): Double = ???
    }`
However, other methods that once accepted `SubLocation`, no longer type check, replacing these with `Location[SubLocation]` does not work either.

Comment: @jackt However you want. If your location is 2d, for example, then define `class Loc2D(val x: Double, val y: Double, name: String) extends Location[Loc2D](name) { def distance(other: Loc2D): Double = math.hypot(this.x - other.x, this.y - other.y) }`. That would be the Euclidean distance on the plane.

Comment: Ah, I omitted the `SubLocation` type when extending `Location`. This has solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need for you to define a type `T` inside your `Location` abstract class. You should proceed as follows:

```
abstract class Location[T <: Location[T]](val name: String) {
  def distance(that: T): Double
}

case class Route[T <: Location[T]](route: List[T]) {
  def measureDistance: Double = {
    def measure(head: T, tail: List[T], acc: Double = 0.0): Double = tail match {
      case Nil => acc
      case h :: t => measure(h, t, head.distance(h) + acc)
    }
    if (route.isEmpty) 0.0
    else measure(route.head, route.tail)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for the scala compiler to know that `type T <: Location` defined in class `Location` is the same type as the type parameter `[T <: Location]` of Route.

I think you will have to chage the signature of `def distance(...)`. I am not sure, but it should work if you define T as type parameter of Location:

```
abstract class Location[T <: Location[T]](val name: String) {
  def distance[T](that: T): Double
}
```