# Scala generic functional way of segmenting a polyline

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, generic-programming

Working on an interesting problem of segmenting a line in space which is represented as Seq[Point]

```
abstract class Point[T] {
    def dimensions: Double

    def distance(rhs: T) : Double

    def linearInterpolate(t: T, ratio: Double) : T
  }
```

can be

```
case class Point2D(x:Double, y:Double) extends Point[Point2D] {
override def dimensions: Double = 2.0

def -(rhs: Point2D): Point2D = Point2D(x - rhs.x, y - rhs.y)
def +(rhs: Point2D): Point2D = Point2D(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y)
def *(rhs: Double): Point2D = Point2D(x * rhs, y * rhs)

override def linearInterpolate(target: Point2D, ratio: Double): Point2D = {
  ratio match {
    case 0.0 => this
    case 1.0 => target
    case _ => this + (target - this) * ratio
  }
}

def dot(rhs: Point2D): Double = x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y

def lengthSquared: Double = this.dot(this)

def length: Double = Math.sqrt(lengthSquared)

override def distance(rhs: Point2D): Double = (rhs - this).length
}
```

What I am looking for is:

```
class SegmentLine(sortedPointsInALine: Seq[Point2D]) {
require(sortedPointsInALine.nonEmpty)

//Main problem to solve
def subSegmentWithAbsolute(segmentLength: Double): Seq[Point2D] = ???

//Helper Function, not sure yet if this is correct yet
def length: Option[Double] = {

  def add(sum: Double, points: Seq[Point2D]): Double = {
    val d = points match {
      case Seq(start, end) => start.distance(end)
    }
    sum + d
  }
  (sortedPointsInALine.headOption, sortedPointsInALine.lastOption) match {
    case (Some(_), Some(_)) => Some(sortedPointsInALine.sliding(2).toSeq.foldLeft(0.0)(add))
    case _ => None
  }
}
}
```

Example usage:

```
val line = Seq(
    Point2D(1, 1),
    Point2D(1, 4)
  )

  val segmentLine = new SegmentLine(line).subSegmentWithAbsolute(1.0)

  val expectedLine = Seq(
    Point2D(1, 1),
    Point2D(1, 2),
    Point2D(1, 3),
    Point2D(1, 4)
  )
```

segmentedLine should be equal to expectedline

Two things I am stuck on:
1) A good segmentation algorithm for line
2) Would Like to make SegmentLine generic enough to take in a Seq of anything that extends Point

Strict functional programming is preferred. Appreciate the help with implementation and design clarifications.

Comment: `2D` and `3D` still not even valid tokens. And why does `distance` return a function `Double => Double`, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what the method should do mathematically? Given a sequence of points and a length, what should the output be?

Comment: You can refactor it using typeclasses: `class SegmentLine[T: PointType](sortedPointsInALine: Seq[T])`

Comment: Looks suspiciously similar to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50757780/2707792).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin though question linked is helpful with the structuring. I was also looking for a good algorithm for sub-segmenting a line too.

Comment: @abroy You've changed the question several times. The API is still weird (unclear what all those functions in the return types are good for). Do you expect to deal with fractal dimensions? Can you write down the `subSegmentWithFoobar`-method for 2d-points? It's just unclear where you are stuck and what exactly your problem is: is it the weird API? Is it the interpolation algorithm? Is it the difficulty with the type-checker? This whole "question" seems like a bunch of disconnected problems without any solution attempts.

Comment: Slept over it and was able to refine the design. Was able to implement a concrete Point2D. The problem should be more clear now as per the usage.

Comment: @abroy Thank you for clarifying the question, looks much better already. Maybe gonna look at it later, here's a (+1) for now to compensate the downvote.